# Enumerate List of Lists and Sorting

Tags: python, list

I am following a tutorial online, and having trouble understanding what the code does.

Here, questions_int is a list of lists containing numbers in the following format:

```
[[7214,1596,2353,4125,3214], [1234,2345,3252,4235], ..... , [4234,5378,4234,5235]]
```

The goal is to sort by the questions by its length to reduce amount of padding time during training the data for sequence 2 sequence model. But I don't understand how the code works and how it helps sorting by length.

```
max_line_length = 20

sorted_questions = []
sorted_answers = []

for length in range(1, max_line_length+1):
    for i in enumerate(questions_int):
        if len(i[1]) == length:
            sorted_questions.append(questions_int[i[0]])
            sorted_answers.append(answers_int[i[0]])
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Excuse me, but what precisely is the question?  What do you not understand?

Comment: If you just don't understand what a particular function does, like `enumerate` (I'm just guessing at what you're question is here, so apologies if I'm wrong), [look it up in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). If you _still_ don't understand it after reading the docs, or if you understand it in general but not how it applies in some line of code, then you can ask a specific question that can be easily answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so let's take this line by line.

1. `for length in range(1, max_line_length+1):` iterates from 1 to max_line_length.  This means `length` will first be equal to `1`, then when the loop finishes `length` will be equal to `2`, etc. until `length is finally equal to`max_line_length` (20 in this case)
2. `for i in enumerate(questions_int):` makes i equal to a tuple of (index, element), meaning that `len(i[1])` will be the length of the ith question.  As `length` increases in value from one, the shortest questions and answers will gradually be added to the lists, hence the `append(` calls within the 2nd for loop
3. The line `sorted_questions.append(questions_int[i[0]])` will append the question at the current index where `len(i[1])==length`.  Remember that i is a tuple of 2 elements, and the first is the index of the current question.  So `questions_int[i[0]]` is the question that has length `length`.
4. Similarly, `answers_int[i[0]]` is the answer corresponding to that question.  So whenever we find a slightly longer question using the `if` condition, the list `sorted_answers` gets longer by 1 with the new answer, and `sorted_questions` does as well

Please ask a follow up question wherever you are confused